# Navigate to a page in Angular 2+ with fixed navbar

Tags: angular

I have a list of option where i want to navigate into each page in each list option . May i know how to do that ?  I just tried router option and all but it doesn't work . The navbar and footer already set at fixed position , content in the background area should change according to menu selection in navbar.

Comment: Please share code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `navigateByUrl` instead of common route method. Let me give an example code

### .html

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
 <li (click)="goToPage('account')">My Account</li>
</ul>
```

### .ts

```
goToPage(path)
{
console.log(data);
this.router.navigateByUrl(path)
}
```

Hope this one will help you

Comment: Thank you. What is that account in goTopage() function?

Comment: Account is a defined component . Please go through [angular.io](http://angular.io) to know more details regarding components. Cheer up!!